# Calculating Var(X)

Tags: probability

Let $\Theta$ be an unknown random variable with mean $1$ and variance $2$. Let $W$ be another unknown random variable with mean $3$ and variance $5$. $\Theta$ and $W$ are independent.

Let: $X_1=\Theta+W$ and $X_2=2\Theta+3W$. We pick measurement $X$ at random, each having probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of being chosen. This choice is independent of everything else.

How does one calculate $Var(X)$ in this case?
Is

$$
Var(X)\;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{2}(Var(\Theta)+Var(W))+\frac{1}{2}(Var(2\Theta)+Var(3W)) \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2}(5Var(\Theta)+10Var(W))?
$$

Comment: Sorry, let me ask you, what is $X $ ?

Comment: X is just a measurement of signal Θ and noise W, we only know that it will be on form of X=Θ+W 50% of the time or X=2Θ+3W the other 50% of the time.


If X=Θ+W, then Var(X)=(Var(Θ)+Var(W)-2Cov(Θ+W))=Var(Θ)+Var(W)=7
since Θ and W are independent.

If X=2Θ+3W, then Var(X)=(Var(2Θ)+Var(3W)=(4Var(Θ)+9Var(W))=53 but I dont know how they should be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Denoting the random index by $I$ we have:

$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E(X\mid I=1)P(I=1)+\mathbb E(X\mid I=1)P(I=1)=\mathbb EX_1.\frac12+\mathbb EX_2.\frac12$$and:

$$\mathbb EX^2=\mathbb E(X^2\mid I=1)P(I=1)+\mathbb E(X^2\mid I=1)P(I=1)=\mathbb EX_1^2.\frac12+\mathbb EX^2_2.\frac12$$
Now use the well known identity:
$$\text{Var}(X)=\mathbb EX^2-(\mathbb EX)^2$$
The equalities $X_1=\Theta+W$ and $X_2=2\Theta+3W$ can be used to find $\mathbb EX_i$ and $\mathbb EX_i^2$ for $i=1,2$.

Answer (score 0):

The choice between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is a coin toss independent of everything else. Let $Y$ equal 1 if $X_1$ is chosen, and 0 if $X_2$ is chosen. Then
$$
X = X_1 Y + X_2(1-Y)\;.
$$
Calculate
$$E(X) = E(X_1Y)+ E[X_2(1-Y)] = 0.5  (EX_1+EX_2)
$$
and
$$E(X^2) = E(X_1^2Y^2) + 2E(X_1X_2Y(1-Y)) + E[X_2^2(1-Y)^2] = 0.5(EX_1^2+EX_2^2)
$$
using independence between $Y$ and everything else, and the facts $Y^2=Y$, $Y(1-Y)=0$, $(1-Y)^2=1-Y$, and $EY=E(1-Y)=0.5$.

Finally calculate the variance using
$$\text{var}(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2\;.$$

Comment: The explanation makes sense, but I couldn't get the right number, unfortunately. Can you correct my calculation? 

$EX_1^2=E(Θ+W)^2=E(Θ^2)+2EΘEW+E(W^2)=(VarΘ+(EΘ)^2)+(VarW+(EW)^2)+2EΘEW=(2+1^2)+(5+3^2)+(2*1*3)=23\\
Similarly\\
EX_2^2=E(2Θ+3W)^2=174?$

Comment: I get $E(X_1^2)=23$ and $E(X_2^2)=174$, same as you.

Comment: Oops, yes it's actually correct, I entered my answer incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, $Var(X_2) = Var(2\Theta + 3W) = 4Var(\Theta) + 9Var(W)$ and
similarly for $Var(X_1)$. However, you cannot average the two variances to get $Var(X)$. This does not take account of the
randomness of the coin toss to decide whether to pick $X_1$ or $X_2.$
[And even if you deterministically chose each $X_i$ alternately, you still could not average the variances because they are, in general, centered on different means.]

Here is a simulation that 'performs' a similar experiment a million times to show you cannot just average the variances of $X_1$ and $X_2$ to get the variance of your $X.$ I used $X_1$ normal with mean 100 and variance 100, and $X_2$ normal with mean 70 and variance 25. (You can, however, average the means.)

```
 x1 = rnorm(10^6, 100, 10)
 x2 = rnorm(10^6, 70, 5)
 b = rbinom(10^6, 1, .5)       # coin tosses
 x = b*x1 + (1-b)*x2
 cbind(x1, x2, x)[1:10,]       # first 10 results
              x1       x2         x
  [1,] 100.67966 70.06460 100.67966  # chose 1st
  [2,]  80.60085 70.76861  70.76861  # chose 2nd
  [3,]  80.97220 69.87782  69.87782  # chose 2nd
  [4,]  99.28911 72.56239  72.56239  # etc...
  [5,]  78.18894 65.62820  65.62820
  [6,] 107.14613 77.80526  77.80526
  [7,]  94.79299 76.17693  94.79299
  [8,]  95.45661 66.13161  66.13161
  [9,] 107.01943 71.48198  71.48198
 [10,] 117.05664 72.13655 117.05664
 var(x1); var(x2); var(x)
 ## 99.89692  # Exact is V(X1) = 100
 ## 25.02683  # Exact is V(X2) = 25
 ## 287.2787  # Approx result using other "Answers"
 mean(x1); mean(x2); mean(x)
 ## 99.9913   # Exact is E(X1) = 100
 ## 69.99634  # Exact is E(X2) = 70
 ## 84.99333  # Exact E(X) IS avg of 100 and 70
```